# What is the fundamental group $\pi (S^2, (0,0,1)) $ of the unit sphere with base point $ (0,0,1)$?

Tags: general-topology, fundamental-groups

I'm trying to find the fundamental group of the unit sphere with base point $(0,0,1)$. Does it matter that my base point is $(0,0,1)$ specifically?

Comment: Do you have a hypothesis? What do you suspect the group to be?

Comment: I am fairly new to fundamental groups, but would it just be the point (0,0,1)?

Comment: Yes, sort of: The identity element of the group is the set of paths that are homotopic to the constant path $t\mapsto(0,0,1)$. The task is then to prove whether or not there is anything else in the group.

Answer (score 1):

In a path connected space $X$, $\pi_1(X,x)\cong\pi_1(X,x')$ for
all $x$, $x'\in X$.

The space $S^n$ is well-known to be simply connected for $n\ge2$.